# MySQL data contains special characters like š and ć, but they are displayed as '?' on the web page. Why?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, character-encoding

I am trying to retrieve a row from the table which contains the value `Boris Borenović`.
Instead, `Boris Borenovi?` is returned.

Both my MySQL database and table have `utf8_unicode_ci` collation set.

My PHP page, which displays data from the table, contains the following header: `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />`. I tried with `charset=utf-8` as well, but it still doesn't work.

The Sql command I am using to query data from the table is `SELECT * FROM contact`, so nothing special there, just boring plain query. I tried with `SELECT * FROM contact COLLATE Latin1_General_CI` but that query can't be executed.

How do I make it work? Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever change the charset of already inserted data? Are your fields in the table also `utf8`? It's not that intelligent to save data within the database as UTF8 but working with ISO-8859-1 charset on the page itself. Try to put your text in `htmlentities()` and post the results here!

Comment: you will need to combine @costis and @Ioannis Karadimas answers to get it working. UTF-8 is the way to go for all you data (utf8 db, utf8 meta charset, utf8 mysql connection)

Comment: my database and connection collation as well as the page encoding are all set to utf8. i still see the stupid question marks and it's making me feel a bit frustrated.

Comment: Have you try the SET NAMES utf8 mentionned by @Ioannis Karadimas. I had a similar issue with accented chars and that part made the deal. My database was set in utf8_general_ci as well as all my db fields that contained text. Mysql was set with charset ut8 and my Web page was set in utf8 too. The only thing that solved the problem was SET NAMES utf8

Comment: I went to the database page, clicked SQL tab and executed `SET NAMES utf8` command. Nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

  $mysql_host = "localhost";

  $mysql_db = "database";
  $mysql_user = "username";
  $mysql_pass = "password";

  $mysql_character = "latin1";
  $mysql_collate = "latin1_bin";

  $db = mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass);
  if(!$db) echo "Cannot connect to the database!";

  mysql_select_db($mysql_db);
  mysql_query("ALTER DATABASE `".$mysql_db."` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET '".$mysql_character."' COLLATE '".$mysql_collate."'");
  $query = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES");
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $table = $row[0];
    mysql_query("ALTER TABLE `".$table."` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET '".$mysql_character."' COLLATE '".$mysql_collate."'");

    $query2 = mysql_query("SHOW columns FROM `".$table."`");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query2)) {
      $column = $row[0];
      $type = $row[1];
      $null = $row[2];
      if($null == "YES") $null = "NULL";
      if($null == "NO") $null = "NOT NULL";
      mysql_query("ALTER TABLE `".$table."` CHANGE COLUMN `".$column."` `".$column."` ".$type." CHARACTER SET '".$mysql_character."' COLLATE '".$mysql_collate."' ".$null);
    }
  }

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer: [can't insert russian text into mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404768/cant-insert-russian-text-into-mysql-database/4404834#4404834) 
You need to configure MySQL to allow utf-8

Comment: The question indicates that the OP is seeing the proper characters in the DB. So the problem is not with the inserts nor the table itself.

Comment: correct BalusC, everything is fine in the db. the problem is located in the php page.

Answer (score 1):

Have you set your connection collation? Try executing `SET NAMES utf8` to set all collations to utf-8, then set your charset to utf-8 as well prior to executing the select statement.

Comment: If that was the only cause, then the OP would likely have seen `Å¡` instead of `?` for a `š`.

Answer (score 0):

Your database is perfectly fine. If you was seeing `?` inside the database itself, then it would have meant that the database table encoding is wrong.

Since you're seeing `?` in the HTTP response, then it means that PHP isn't been instructed to write characters as UTF-8 to the response. Check step 3 of this [PHP UTF-8 cheatsheet](http://developer.loftdigital.com/blog/php-utf-8-cheatsheet).

If you're then seeing for example `Å¡` instead of `š`, then you need to execute [`mysql_set_charset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php) with `utf8` prior to the `SELECT` as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, BalusC. I changed the php.ini file according to the step 3 in the instructions, but the error remains the same. Any more ideas?

Comment: Did you install mbstring as well? See step 2. Sorry for not mentioning it directly in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

My way is:

```
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'UTF8'");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET_CLIENT='UTF8'");
```

Put this code after you connect on database

```
(mysql_select_db($Database);)
```

Comment: he needs to run that on every field, table and database