# mysql 5.0 unable to store utf8

Tags: java, mysql, database, utf-8, character-encoding

Iv'e configured mysql 5.0 to store utf8 characters.I checked it with following queries :

---

```
SELECT character_set_name FROM information_schema.`COLUMNS` C
WHERE table_schema = "oprdb"
  AND table_name = "rtable"
  AND column_name = "rtxt";
```

the result is `utf8`

---

```
SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM rtable
```

this shows me `collation` as `utf8_general_ci`

---

```
show variables like "character_set_database";
show variables like "collation_database";
```

this too shows `utf8` in result

---

it seems that mysql is configured correctly.
i am getting text from an html page where user types text in a textfield and i submit that text to servlet using  jquery post.

My html page has this on top--

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

i also added this into my form --

```
enctype="text/plain;charset=UTF-8"
```

In my servlet  the first line in doPost is

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

and after that i just save that text in database.But the problem is that,i can't store this kind of text

```
 Hiki iaʻu ke ʻai i ke aniani; ʻaʻole nō lā au e ʻeha.
 Я магу есці шкло, яно мне не шкодзіц
```

is their anything i am missing?

**EDIT:**

This is my datasource configuration..

```
<Resource auth                = "Container" 
            driverClassName     = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
            factory             = "org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory" 
            initialSize         = "10" 
            logAbandoned        = "true"
            maxActive           = "50" 
            maxIdle             = "2" 
            maxWait             = "10000" 
            name                = "jdbc/oprdb" 
            username            = "root"
            password            = "123456" 
            removeAbandoned     = "true" 
            removeAbandonedTimeout = "60"  
            type                   = "javax.sql.DataSource" 
            url                    = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/oprdb" />
```

Comment: what error you are getting while saving text ?

Comment: no error ... text get saved in table but in weired form  like this  :::...            :Î¤á½´ Î³Î»á¿¶ÏƒÏƒÎ± Î¼Î¿á¿¦ á¼”Î´Ï‰ÏƒÎ±Î½ á¼‘Î»Î»Î·Î½Î¹Îºá½´

Comment: and whats ur jdbc driver url?

Comment: Check this answer out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404768/cant-insert-russian-text-into-mysql-database/4404834#4404834

Comment: Try to use `SET NAMES 'UTF_8'` (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html). It tells the server the character set of the incoming messages.

Comment: @CostisAivalis  `:(`  didn't work for me ...

Comment: @alain.janinm  i really don't know where to use `SET NAME` in my app... can you please explain a bit..

Comment: @JAVAGeek In your tables creation script, before the CREATE TABLE statement.

Comment: @alain.janinm  tried..but didn't work...

Comment: Ok and have you tried with cyrillic charset (I guess your text is Russian no?) http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-cyrillic-sets.html

Comment: Mmmm, looking at your error, it may not be a problem with mysql, but with the way you get your string from the request. A good way to check it is to display your string's length(). It should display the length in characters. If you get twice the length, it is because the string has not been read correctly (each byte of the UTF-8 value has been interpreted as a char).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your url to `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/oprdb?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8`
for utf-8 support

Comment: Try copy your text and manually update in MySql table column using some MySQl GUI tool, to verify its not mysql issue.

Answer (score 0):

These are the only settings in MySQL Workbench in my system:

[image]

The result is the addition of these two lines:

```
character-set-server = utf8
character-set-filesystem = utf8
```

in the **/etc/mysql/my.cnf** file.

Make sure that the collation of your database table is utf8.