# Unable to save address properly of different languages in database

Tags: android, phpmyadmin, geolocation, reverse-geocoding

**SCENARIO:**

I am creating an app which fetches user current location, and using the fetched latitude and longitude, I find address from it using the below code:

```
private String getAddress(double latitude,double longitude) {
    Geocoder geocoder;
    List<Address> addresses;
    String adress="";
    geocoder=new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(),Locale.ENGLISH);

    try {
        addresses=geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude,longitude,1);
        String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0); // If any additional address line present than only, check with max available address lines by getMaxAddressLineIndex()
        String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
        String state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
        String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
        String postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
        String knownName = addresses.get(0).getFeatureName();
        adress=address+","+city+","+state+","+country+","+postalCode;
        // Here 1 represent max location result to returned, by documents it recommended 1 to 5
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return adress;
}
```

And address alongwith latitude and longitude is sent to server using web services.

**PROBLEM:**

This code works fine in my country(**i.e India**) but in another country like Kazakhstan, I don't get address in proper English Language. It looks something like this.

[image: Location]

When I searched for solving this problem I came around following solutions:

1. Earlier I was using **Default Locale** for getting address from lat, long which was causing issue. So I have **changed Locale to English** which somewhat solved the problem as it now returns in English.
2. I also changed **database collation** in php backend to **UTF-8 General CI** but problem still exist.

I tested my app by using mock location apps but was not able to reproduce this issue.

What are the possible cause and solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to resolve this problem. It was a php backend issue. To solve this I had to add following line after connecting to database.

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8')
```

For furhter reference check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404768/cant-insert-russian-text-into-mysql-database) link

Alongwith this there was problem with Multipart Request too. I was sending location address alongwith other parameter via Multipart request using standard http library, which was causing issue when entered in php database.

To solve this we use `UrlEncode/Decode` on app as well as backend side. So we sent address in encoded form and when decoded on server side, address was proper this time.

Hope this can help anyone.